# How do I show an icon on a JLabel when clicking on a JMenuItem?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have put an icon in a `JMenuItem`. I want this icon to show on a `JLabel` when I click on the `JMenuItem`, how can I achieve that?

This is my code:

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package labwork5;


/**
 *
 * @author haseeb shah
 */
public class lab5part2frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form lab5part2frame
     */
    public lab5part2frame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, jLabel1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${icon}"), this, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("iconImage"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        jLabel1.setIcon(jMenuItem1.getRolloverSelectedIcon());
        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
        jLabel1.setComponentPopupMenu(jMenuItem1.getComponentPopupMenu());
        jLabel1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        jLabel1.addContainerListener(new java.awt.event.ContainerAdapter() {
            public void componentRemoved(java.awt.event.ContainerEvent evt) {
                jLabel1ComponentRemoved(evt);
            }
        });

        jMenu1.setText("Mobile Networks");

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, jLabel1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${icon}"), jMenu1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("actionCommand"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        jMenu1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jMenu1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jMenuItem1.setAction(java.swing.posticon(jLabel1));
        jMenuItem1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/labwork5/province icon.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jMenuItem1.setText("Zain");

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, jLabel1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${displayedMnemonic}"), jMenuItem1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("actionCommand"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuItem2.setText("Mobily");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuItem3.setText("Gomo");
        jMenuItem3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem3);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(95, 95, 95)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 191, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(114, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(72, 72, 72)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 94, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(113, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        bindingGroup.bind();

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
   
    
    private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void jLabel1ComponentRemoved(java.awt.event.ContainerEvent evt) {                                         
            
    }                                        

    private void jMenu1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
            this.transferFocus();
    }                                   

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(lab5part2frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(lab5part2frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(lab5part2frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(lab5part2frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new lab5part2frame().setVisible(true);
              
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
    private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for a working example of adding an Icon to a JLabel. In your case in the ActionListener of the JMenuItem you would need to 1) read the image 2) create the Icon 3) add the Icon to the label.

Comment: Are you using [JFormDesigner](https://www.formdev.com/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `jlabel.setIcon(Icon icon)` method.
Don't forget to use `jlabel.revalidate()` and `jlabel.repaint()` after update your GUI.